# Salvar dados do loop for no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, loop, for

Bom dia estou desenvolvendo uma parte financeira onde eu preencho um determinado formulário que é data do vencimento, valor integral, valor com desconto, ano letivo, porcentagem do desconto e quantidade de parcela porem antes de salvar essa parcelas no banco de dados criei um loop for para gerar as parcelas de acordo com a quantidade preenchida no formulario e como resultado ele me traz as parcelas só visual para o usuario verificar se esta tudo certo ex:

10/01/2018 = R$ 400.00

10/02/2018 = R$ 400.00

10/03/2018 = R$ 400.00

10/04/2018 = R$ 400.00

agora minha duvida é o seguinte como faço para recuperar essas quantidades de parcelas geradas  e salvar no banco de dados por que se eu colocar um botao fora do for eu nao consigo pegar por exemplo 4 parcelas e salvar no bd e só apenas uma.

```
<form role="form" method="post" class="">
<div class="form-body">


<div class="form-group">

<label>ano letivo</label>
<input class="form-control spinner" type="text" name="ano_letivo" value="<? 
php echo date('Y'); ?>" />

</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="nMatricula">Numero de Matricula</label>

<input type="text" name="matricula" class="form-control" id="nMatricula" 
placeholder="Matricula"> 
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<label for="nomealuno">Nome do Aluno</label>
<input type="text" disabled="" name="nome_aluno" class="form-control" 
id="nomealuno" placeholder="nome do aluno"> 
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>valor da mensalidade</label>

<input class="form-control spinner" type="text" name="valor1" id="valor1" 
value="583.02" />
</div>
```

desconto %

```
<input class="form-control spinner" type="text" name="desconto1" 
id="desconto1" onblur="calcValor()" />
</div>                 

<div class="form-group">
<label>valor total</label>

<input class="form-control spinner" type="text" name="total" id="total" 
value="0.00" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>nº de parcelas</label>

<input class="form-control spinner" type="text" name="n_parcelas" value="12" 
/>
</div>      

<div class="form-group">
<label>dia de vencimento</label>

<input class="form-control spinner" type="text" name="dt_vencimento" 
id="dt_vencimento" />
</div>                                                       
</div>
<div class="form-actions">
<button type="submit" name="gerar" class="btn green-meadow">Visualizar 
Parcelas</button>
<a href="home.php" class="btn red">Cancelar</a>
</div>
</form>

<?php 

if (isset($_POST['gerar'])) {

$vl_mensalidade = $_POST['valor1'];
$matricula = $_POST['matricula'];
$ano_letivo = $_POST['ano_letivo'];
$desconto = $_POST['desconto1'];
$vl_desconto = $_POST['total'];
$n_parcelas = $_POST['n_parcelas'];
$dataPrimeiraParcela = $_POST['dt_vencimento'];

if($dataPrimeiraParcela != null){
$dataPrimeiraParcela = explode( "/",$dataPrimeiraParcela);
$dia = $dataPrimeiraParcela[0];
$mes = $dataPrimeiraParcela[1];
$ano = $dataPrimeiraParcela[2];
} else {
$dia = date("d");
$mes = date("m");
$ano = date("Y");
} 

for ($x=0; $x < $n_parcelas; $x++) {

$vencimento = date("d/m/Y",strtotime("+".$x." month",mktime(0, 0, 
0,$mes,$dia,$ano)));

echo "Vencimento: ".$vencimento." - ".$vl_desconto;

}                                                              
}
?>
```

Comment: poste seu codigo php que geral as parcelas e o html para podermos ajudar melhor

Comment: pronto acho  que da pra entender...lkkkk ruim pra organizar o codigo aki

Comment: aquele ultimo echo coloquei assim só como exemplo mais na verdade no sistema aqui esta estilizado com todas as informaçoes a duvida realmente é como eu pego esses dados do for e salvo do bd